# Support for log4j2 in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

The Spring Boot reference documentation has good coverage for logback, but hardly any for log4j2. I am specifically interested in profile specific configuration; which is documented well for logback; has anyone tried the same for log4j2?

Comment: Use logging.level option are there . Please use in application.properties file...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how I solved this issue. I renamed my log4j2.xml configuration file to the Spring-boot specific log4j2-spring.xml. I then removed the log levels definitions from it, hence the file was left with just my appender definitions. I then created profile specific application-{profile}.properties files for each of my profiles. There I defined the [log level](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-levels) using the information from the [Logging chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) in the reference manual.

```
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

Comment: Why downgrade without giving an explanation? Especially when I have written that I have solved my issue this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `logging.file` configuration property.

For example, if you have two profiles `dev` and `prod`, you can define two log4j config files:

- `log4j2-dev.xml`
- `log4j2-prod.xml`

Then in `application-dev.properties` define:

```
logging.file=log4j2-dev.xml
```

And in `application-prod.properties` define:

```
logging.file=log4j2-prod.xml
```

Comment: Thank you, This approach is good too. But I like my approach a little better. There are several ways to skin a cat.

Comment: `logging.file` configuration property defines where the application should log and shouldn't point to the configuration file